# Uncaught Action failed: parent versus child Components

Tags: lightning, aura-id

My Parent Component

```
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.editProductGenerationGrid}" disabled="{!v.disablebutton}" variant="brand" aura:id="Edit1" label="Edit" />  
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.updateNotifications}" disabled="{!v.disablebutton}" variant="brand" aura:id="Update1" label="Update" />
     <c:HBCProductDevelopment aura:id="porductDevelopmentDetails" porductDevelopmentDetails="{!v.Product_Generation_Grid}" />
```

Helper

```
updateNotifications : function(component,resolve, reject){
         var action = component.get("c.sendUpdateNotification");
         var inputVal = component.find('inputCmp');
         var value = inputVal.get("v.value");
        alert(value);
        action.setParams({
                "hbcProductGenerationGrid": component.get("v.Product_Generation_Grid"),
            "sectionName" :component.get("v.currentSectionName")
            });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                    if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                        alert('Record Updated');
                    }
                else{
                }
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

My Child Component

```
<lightning:layoutitem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
            <lightning:input name="System Plan Name"
                label="System Plan Name" disabled="{!v.disableSection}"
                             type="text"  maxlength="100" aura:id="inputCmp" value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails.HBC_System_Plan_Name__c}"/>
        </lightning:layoutitem>
```

Now my requirement is I need to check whether System Plan Name is null or not. To check this I need to get the aura:id value in my Parent. How can I get the value their?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the value of the `Product_Generation_Grid` attribute from your parent to your `porductDevelopmentDetails` attribute in your child.

Then, the Lightning system binds the two values.

So, in your parent, you only have to check this: `$A.util.isEmpty(component.get("v.Product_Generation_Grid").HBC_System_Plan_Name__c)) == false`

Comment: Thats Perfect.But when I try to display the error message `var inputVal = component.get("v.Product_Generation_Grid").HBC_System_Plan_Name__c; if(isNaN(inputVal)) component.set("v.errors", [{message:"Input not a number:"}]);` it is not getting displayed. Can you please update the answer

Comment: Is there any reason why you set your lightning:input as type text instead of directly set it to number?